# High CPU load average; how to find the root cause?

Tags: linux, process, cpu, uptime, load-average

It is hard task to find the root cause of CPU load average
many commands are used to give partial picture.

I am not sure if somewhere we can find a tool that knows how many CPU's we have on machine and verify the load average and give results if load average is more then normal.

And if load average is high, then find the root cause.

## What I have already find:

on machine we find the following ( actually not )

1. no network problem
2. no disks problem
3. log as messages is clean without errors

Any tips about, how to find the root cause of high CPU load average?

Comment: Have you heard of FlameGraphs?  http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `perf` - I reckon it is the perfect tool for finding the information you are after.

Here's a few resources:

- [Start with Julia Evans' excellent `perf` ezine](https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/16/new-perf-zine/)
- [`perf` examples](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html)
- [How to analyze your system with `perf` and python](https://opensource.com/article/18/7/fun-perf-and-python)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering the same thing and checking out [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) to help answer this question.

When something causes high load average:

- it's not always obvious and
- you don't always have time to investigate when it's happening

Munin records certain data about your system so when the load average spikes you can go back and investigate (e.g. compare to log files).

See http://munin-monitoring.org/

This [blog entry](https://www.tummy.com/articles/isolating-heavy-load/) has a number of approaches, including Munin